# getting information from scada system on android application in run time

Tags: android, alarm, scada

Is it possible to create an Android application to display the alarm summary from a SCADA system?
If yes, what must I do?

Answer (score 2):

Depends which SCADA system you have, you need to be more specific with your question.

A lot of SCADA systems hold the alarms in an SQL database so you should be able to pull something from that.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to implement this, could be to create a TCP server internally in SCADA (if your SCADA allows that) and make it reply to data requests from clients. Then you create Android application which will periodically poll that TCP server and display gathered data (alarms in your case). If your SCADA software does not allow creating TCP servers internally, then you can create an external TCP server in some common programming language, which will periodically poll SCADA to gather needed data via some protocol that SCADA understands (like DDE, OPC...), and provide that data to Android clients. Alternatively, if your alarms can be found in PLC then you can skip SCADA and address PLC directly using protocol that PLC understands - like MODBUS, S7, FINS...).

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small scada system for Android called UniGO.
You will find an alarmsystem inside that application. Might be something you looking for.
It has a background service for polling your HMI/PLC. Vibration and noice, led status.
If you use modbus TCP/IP it will work for you.

Best Regards
Mikael

Comment: Please give me a suggestion or code as that helps me to develop a small tutorial for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create an Android application to display the alarm summary from [SCADA-LTS](https://github.com/sdtabilit/Scada-LTS/tree/develop-sdtabilit) system?

You can:

- connect to our SCADA using SOAP or REST APIs,
- or display directly in webbrowser alarm summary page from SCADA-LTS.